# Creating Calculated Fields in Google Datastudio

Tags: categories, looker-studio, calculated-field

I would like to create categories based on a count of variable.

```
 CASE
      WHEN COUNT(variable) = 1 THEN "1"
      WHEN COUNT(variable) = 2 THEN "2"
      WHEN COUNT(variable) = 3 THEN "3"
      WHEN COUNT(variable) = 4 THEN "4"
      WHEN COUNT(variable) >= 5 THEN ">5"
    END
```

I get an error that says that my formula is not valid. However, I cannot see where the mistake is and Google does not offer help in this regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This takes a little getting used to in Data Studio, but you can't use all functions inside of a `CASE` statement (as noted in the [documentation](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7020724?hl=en#functions-in-case-statements)).

Here's how you can work around this limitation:

1. Create a new calculated field with the value of `COUNT(variable)`
2. Set the new field's aggregation type to `Sum` in the field list
3. Then create your `CASE` statement formula referencing that new field

If you don't want this extra field showing up in reports, you can disable it in the data source (it can still be used by your other formula).

Also note that the input of `COUNT` itself cannot be an aggregate value (e.g. result of `SUM` or a metric with the aggregation type set).

This is an incredibly frustrating bit of Data Studio, as you end up with a lot of these fields floating around and it adds an extra step. The unhelpful error message definitely doesn't help either.